# Would it be possible to start a modern airliner from cold & dark during flight?

Tags: safety, jet

Imagine a suicidal pilot or disturbed passenger who gets access to cockpit, messes with the buttons. He shuts down engines, IRS, and battery, it's the middle of the night at cruise altitude.
Would it be possible to restart everything during flight and land safely ?

Comment: This is a pretty broad question, since it would depend on a lot of things. Aircraft type, altitude not to mention the human factors involved. Unless you are just looking for an answer saying "Yes, probably", you should try to narrow down your question and add more details.

Comment: if he vandalises the buttons, how could they then be used to restart the aircraft systems?

Comment: @jwenting I meant by vandalize just messing with state of buttons.

Comment: I'd not classify that as vandalism. Any competent pilot would not assume the state of anything when entering a clean cockpit, let alone one where an unauthorised person had gained entry.